# Exact Simple Interest Problem

Tags: economics

Determine the **exact** simple interest on **1,000,000** invested for the period from **October 24,1987 to January 7, 1990**; if the rate of interest is **17%**.

What I've tried:

October 24, 1987 to October 24, 1988 -> 365 days

October 24, 1998 to October 24, 1989 -> 365 days

October 24, 19 1989 to January 7, 1990 -> 75 days

I = Pin = $(1,000,000)(\frac{0.17}{365})(365 + 365 + 365) = 374,931.51$

But the answer should be: **93,785.079.**

Any ideas what I got wrong? Thank you~

Comment: Some banks consider that a year is 360 days instead of 365. I don't know if it's the case here, but just saying ... Also, you probably want to use compound interest, am I right? So you need to raise numbers to a power, instead of adding/multiplying.

Comment: @MattiP. The question states "exact" so I used 365 days instead of 360. Then it also states "simple interest" so I used the formula for S.I. Sadly, I didn't get the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

$$\mbox{October } 24-31 \mbox{ is } 7 \mbox{ days}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{Total days in }1987 \mbox{ is }68 \mbox{ days} $$

$$\mbox{November } 30 \mbox{ days}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{Total days in }1988 \mbox{ is }366 \mbox{ days} $$

$$\mbox{December } 31 \mbox{ days}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{Total days in }1989 \mbox{ is }365 \mbox{ days} $$

$$\mbox{October } 1-7 \mbox{ is } 7 \mbox{ days}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{Total days in }1990 \mbox{ is }7 \mbox{ days} $$

So, Number of interest days $=68+366+365=806$

Number of days from $1987$ to $1990$ is $=365+366+365+365=1461$

So, $I=1,000,000(0.17)\left(\dfrac{806}{1461}\right)=93,785.079$

Answer (score 1):

This problem involves exact simple interest in a period of more than a year and covers year 1988 which is a leap year (366days/year). Hence the calculation for each year must be separated and then summed up. Hence

Oct. 24 to Oct. 31, 1987 is 7 days

Nov. 1 to  Dec 31, 1987 is 30+31=61 days

Total number of days for year 1987 is 7+61=68 days

Total number of days for year 1988 (leap year) is 366 days

Total number of days for year 1989 (ordinary year) is 365 days

Total number of days for year 1990 is (Jan 1 to Jan 7) 7 days

I(1987) = 1,000,000(0.17)(68/365) = 31,671.23

I(1988) = 1,000,000(0.17)(366/366) = 170,000.00

I(1989) = 1,000,000(0.17)(365/365) = 170,000.00

I(1990) = 1,000,000(0.17)(7/365) = 3,260.27

I(total) = 31,671.23+170,000(2)+3,260.27 = 374,931.50

Note: The answer for this problem could not be lower than the interest for a year because this involves more than two years. The interest for a year is 170,000.00 already as shown in my calculation above, for more than two years its should have an interest of more than the double of a years interest.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by stating your main assumption about the time interval corresponding to the given interest rate: is it one year, or is it the four years including the investment period?